# image returns value "null"

Tags: javascript, html, image, null

I have a javascript code that points to an image using `getElementById`. But when I debug it in firebug, it says that my variable has a value of "null". Here is my code:

```
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

image.src = "imageone.png";
```

Comment: Most likely `document.getElementById('myImage')` returns `null` because it fails to find an element with `id="myImage"`.

Comment: Does your `img` have `id="myImage"` in it?

Comment: yes, I checked countless times...

Comment: Your code is probably "naked" in a `<script>` block at the top of the page. Move it to the very end of the `<body>`.

Comment: The `id` is case-sensitive, also it won't work if the element is inside an `iframe` in the document from where you're executing `document.getElementById`, and finally the image may not be present in the DOM by the time your script executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there is no element with that id.

If the element actually have that id, then the reason is that the element hasn't been parsed yet when the code runs. Put it in the `load` event to run it after the entire page has been parsed:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  image.src = "imageone.png";
};
```

Alternatively, you can put the script block in the `body` element, below the image tag.